# Jquery amcharts With Time Based Data

Tags: jquery, charts, amcharts

I am trying to implement the below example but with some changes.
         http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-irregular-time/

```
Requirement:
     1. User will select date and data will display only for that day with 1 hour difference like 00am 1.00am 2.00am....24.00pm like that
     2. Graph should have zoom functionality. lets say if user has selected slot between 1.00 am to 2.00am then graph should generate showing the data for every 10mins
     3. Now lets say if user selects 30-60 minutes then user should get graph with every 5 min.
```

Answer (score 0):

I added an example here with a [Serial chart](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart): https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/4a85bbd1cb355b0370835078c5b0bbce?editors=1010

The labels auto adjust depending on the zoom and scroll positions. This is respecting the chart's best fit for the label. The [minimum period](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#minPeriod) of 5 minutes is respected.

You will need to set the data to the chart based on the date selected by the user as in:

```
chart.dataProvider = data;
chart.validateData();
```

If you need more selections based on periods, you may need to use a [Stock chart](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/multiple-panels/).